# How can you move/copy all files of a specific file extension to a directory in windows vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, file-management, file-transfer

How can i move all files of the same extension into another folder using `cmd`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move a file to archive folder in cmd using wildcards](https://superuser.com/q/517486/173513) and [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/173513)

Answer (score 20):

To copy, can use the `copy` command with wildcards:

```
copy *.<extension> <other folder>
```

And if you to move your files instead: use the `move` the same way:

```
move *.<extension> <other folder>
```

Comment: Why **copy** when user wants to use **move**? `move *.<extension> <other folder>` works. (Edit: Ah, I see he wrote move/copy in the title, although only move in the question.)

Comment: You're right... I read too fast:)

Comment: What if I want to move files with two different extensions ?

Comment: The first idea that comes to mind is... issue the command twice?

Comment: Here is an example to make things easier: ```d:\test> move *.dll d:\F\ ```  the \ at the end of the folder name is needed otherwise you get an error: `Cannot move multiple files to a single file.`

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of moving all files of the `jpg` format from the `C:\` to `D:\pictures\` using cmd.

Simply replace `jpg` with whatever format you wish and then change the to and from locations and you're sorted.

```
for /r C:\ %f in (*.jpg) do @copy "%f" D:\pictures\
```

Comment: A bit convoluted for such a simple task.  Wildcards are a much better answer.

Comment: I forgot about Wildcards until the other answer was posted sadly, changing my answer to that now would be a bit unfair on the other poster haha.