# DOS command to rename with part of the original file name

Tags: rename

I have many files named like this: 
`YYY.XXXXXX`

and i need to write a DOS batch command to rename like this: 
`YYYXXXXXX.ZZZ`

YYY and ZZZ are fixed string, only XXXXXX is variable.

tried this with no success:
`rename YYY.?????? YYY??????.ZZZ`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?

Comment: Tried to rename like above with no success. It does work with a source filename without "." in the middle. I could find a workaround by deleting the "." in the filename

Comment: James L has a good solution for your problem. The RENAME command alone cannot do what you want. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](http://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) to get an idea of what you *can* do with RENAME.

Comment: Thanks dbenham, this is like a goldmine, it's on my bookmarks already :)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `for` statement to do this because it gives you access to the filename and the extension separately:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %i in ('dir /b yyy.*') do ren "%i.%j" "%i%j.zzz"
```

Using `tokens=1,2 delims=.` causes it to split the value returned by `dir /b yyy.*` on the `.` into the `%i` and `%j` variables, where `%i` is the filename (or 'yyy'), and `%j` is the variable extension (without the leading dot `.`).

Use the command above if you are typing it directly from the command prompt.  From a batch file, you need to double all of the `%` symbols like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %%i in ('dir /b yyy.*') do ren "%%i.%%j" "%%i%%j.zzz"
```

Make sure you run this command from the folder where all of the `yyy.xxxxxx` files reside.

Comment: +1 - I could not figure out how to get the extension without the period! I guess that's why I like powershell better...

Comment: +1, but better to use `"tokens=1*"` in case XXXXXX contains `.`

Comment: @dbenham - good catch, `tokens=1*` is much better.

Comment: This answer should have been accepted, maybe by the moderators, because it is actually excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a point, before trying to use `ren` or any other command, first try a `echo` to see what would be done, so instead of:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %i in ('dir /b yyy.*') do ren "%i.%j" "%i%j.zzz"
```

First do (to see what commands would be run):

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %i in ('dir /b yyy.*') do @(echo ren "%i.%j" "%i%j.zzz")
```

After the output show that the commands are what you want, just remove the `echo`.