# How to batch rename and remove last characters

Tags: windows, rename

In Windows XP, I'm trying to figure out how to batch rename and remove the last characters of filenames.

Example of removing last 4 characters before file extenstion:
file.doc.pdf --> file.pdf

I could do:

```
ren *.pdf *.
ren *.doc *.pdf
```

Though this wouldn't work well if there are already other PDFs in the folder.

Not sure if the FOR command is needed here.

Comment: For removing: What about using two dots? `ren *.doc. *.` This way other files with .doc extension don't get touched.

Comment: @nixda: `*.doc.` won't work (file not found).

Answer (score 2):

If your file names do not contain any periods other than at the end (.doc.pdf), the following will work:

```
for /f "delims=." %a in ('dir /b *.doc.pdf') do ren "%~a.doc.pdf" "%~a.pdf"
```

Comment: If you want you can insert an `echo` before `ren` to preview all the renaming operations.

Comment: Karan, your command works, but only if I paste it into the command window, not from the batch file. Any ideas?

Comment: Of course, in a batch file you must double every % sign. So each % will become %%. Try it and see!

Comment: BTW, if this and my previous answer helped you don't forget to [accept them](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) using the green check mark to the left (click it so it becomes filled). Thanks!

Comment: @Karan - There is actually a surprisingly simple solution using only a single REN command :) See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/734969/109090)

Answer (score 2):

`ren * *. -> will give you 'file.doc'
repeat above command -> will give you 'file'
ren * *.pdf -> will give 'file.pdf'`

Answer (score 0):

```
ren *.doc.pdf ????????????????????.pdf
```

Just make sure the target mask has at least as many `?` as the longest base file name.

For an explanation as to why this works, see [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090)

Answer (score -1):

file.doc.pdf --> file.doc:

```
for %I in (*.doc.pdf) do rename "%~nI.pdf" "%~nI"
```

file.doc --> file.pdf

```
for %I in (*.doc) do rename "%~nI.doc" "%~nI.pdf"
```

Comment: Sorry, but -1. You need to use quotes or both commands will fail if the filenames have spaces. Also, instead of renaming .doc.pdf to .pdf, your first command will actually rename to .doc