# How to remove a double file extension?

Tags: windows, command-line, filenames

I had a terrible thing happen to Win 10 that resulted in me deleting my favor Music Folder. I was able to recover all music using Recuva. However, once all songs were restored the program added an extra extension to each file.

For example: VLC media file (. mp3) (. mp3). This double extension has been added to all my music and now I can't play any of them and I don't know how to correct the double extension.

Comment: Write a small C/C++ program to loop through the files in a directory, take the file name, and perform a string replace on ".mp3.mp3" to ".mp3"

Comment: If all the files have this issue, you could use a batch script to remove the last 4 characters of each file name. Here's two questions that should point you in the right direction: (better) https://superuser.com/questions/236820/how-do-i-remove-the-same-part-of-a-file-name-for-many-files-in-windows-7/236887 (worth reading) https://superuser.com/questions/608128/how-to-batch-rename-and-remove-last-characters

Comment: Other questions worth reading too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410982/bat-rename-files-name-remove-first-x-characters-and-last-x-characters and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931611/remove-last-characters-from-my-filenames-in-windows

Comment: You're probably better off taking an existing script like music2myear said, but you can also use [Total Commander](www.ghisler.com) to rename all the files. It has a multi-rename tool that lets you rename multiple files in various ways. Removing the extension (or changing it) is really easy with it.

Comment: Ha ha, @Ramhound.  Maybe I'm just a bit too tired, but that made me laugh :)  Thank you.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the great help! I really appreciate you!. I was able to successfully batch change all file extensions. However, they still won't play, using any of my media players! I wonder if any of you have tips on repairing Mp3 files? I am truly not ready to give up on over 4000 songs. I guess I'll have to? If nothing else works! Again. Thanks greatly for your assistance! 

RKL.