# Is it possible to change a filename prefix using the rename command with wildcards?

Tags: windows, command-line, rename

I have read as much of [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards) as I can understand, and still cannot decide if there is some wildcard combination you can use to make RENAME do this:

```
Old file names: abc001.txt, abc002.txt, abc003.txt, ... etc
New file names: demo_001.txt, demo_002.txt, demo_003.txt, ... etc
or: x001.txt, x002.txt, x003.txt, ... etc
or: file01.txt, file02.txt, file03.txt, ... etc
```

What I do know is that `rename abc*.txt xyz*.txt` will change all `abc` prefixes to `xyz`, but only because `abc` and `xyz` are of identical length. Is there a simple rename command which will cope with either a shorter or longer prefix... or do you have to use a batch process to carry out such renames?

Comment: I know that it’s not exactly the answer to your specific question, but for these tasks I usually use [RenameIt!](http://sourceforge.net/projects/renameit/) utility.

Comment: What Windows version do you have?

Comment: I'm mostly on Win 7, but also need a solution for XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No, you cannot change the length of a file name prefix like you want using just the RENAME command with wildcards. It will require some amount of more complex scripting, or else a non-standard 3rd party tool.

If you read the rules carefully, you will see that the wildcards in the source mask have no bearing in the rename result - they only filter which files are renamed. The non-wildcard prefix characters in the target mask substitute one for one with the characters in the original name.

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell for your first example you could use:

```
Dir C:\folder | ren –NewName {$_.name -replace "abc","demo_"}
```

Add `-whatif` as last parameter if you want to test the command before executing it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do it with [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm), a command interpreter whose `REN` command supports regular expressions:

```
ren ::abc(\d+.txt) ::demo_\1
```

Without regular expressions, it's still a one-liner.  One simply uses the `@INSTR[]` variable function and the `FOR` command:

```
for i in (abc*.txt) do ren %i demo_%@instr[3,,%i]
```

### Further reading

- JP Software. [*REN*](http://jpsoft.com/help/ren.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.
- JP Software. [*FOR*](http://jpsoft.com/help/for.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.
- JP Software. [*@INSTR*](http://jpsoft.com/help/f_instr.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.