# Batch Renaming Automation *_2.* TO *.*

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

i am in the process of renaming multiple files from *_2.* to *.*
I want to remove the "_2" suffix

My first workaround is trying

```
   ren *_2.* *.*
```

but this does not work.
Help is apperciated.

Comment: About how many files do you need to rename?  Are they all the sale width in terms of number of characters?

Comment: About 1000 files and they have different number of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You can use this batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%G in (*_2.*) do (
set new=%%~nG
set new=!new:~0,-2!
ren "%%~G" "!new!%%~xG"
)
```

### How it works

1. List all files matching `*_2.*`.
2. Remove the `_2` suffix from each file name (`%%~nG`) by stripping the last 2 characters.
3. Append the original extension (`%%~xG`) to the new name.
4. Rename the file.

### Test cases

```
__2.bin --> _.bin
abc_def_2.txt --> abc_def.txt
2014_02_23_2.log --> 2014_02_23.log
```

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)
- [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this as a little .cmd :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*_2.*) do (
set fnm=%%a
echo ren !fnm! !fnm:_2.=.!
)
```

which **seems** to do what you expect (remove the echo if satisfied by test run).

I just see a possible issue if you have several `_2.` in the filename

**EDIT** : replaced incomplete proposal as per suggestion

Comment: Replacing a substring can give unwanted side-effects. Let's say you have a file called `2014_02_23_2.log`. If you just remove all `_2` by replacing it with an empty string, you would end up with a file called `2014_023.log`. Not really what the OP wanted.

Comment: Should I fix it, since anyway I am obviously "out-answered" with better batchlets ?

Comment: The answer itself is not entirely wrong, but you should improve it by elaborating a little more, add some warning, and possibly provide a working example code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it in PowerShell (it's a one-liner so be sure to scroll to the right):

```
gci PATH\TO\YOUR\FOLDER\ | ? {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.BaseName.EndsWith("_2")} | ren -NewName {("{0}{1}" -f $_.BaseName.Substring(0, $_.BaseName.Length-2), $_.Extension)}
```

**gci** is an alias of Get-ChildItem - enter the path to your folder here. If you have subfolders then add **-Recurse** after the path

**?** is an alias of Where-Object - here we loop through the items and check it is NOT a folder and its name ends with "_2" (excluding the file extension).

**ren** - Rename-Item - finally we rename the files that passed the Where-Object filter. Using Substring we just cut off the two last characters of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, under the assumption that the patterns is really `_2.*` and not `_2*.*` (nothing after digit 2) and there is only one underscore in the name as **and31415** correctly pointed out - as it will remove anything from `_` (underscore) up to extension

`for %i in (*_2.*) do (@for /f "delims=_ tokens=1" %j in ("%~ni") do @echo ren "%i" "%j%~xi")`

**Please note:**
- it's one line, as run directly from command line
- it now **only echoes (prints)** ren command to console. After you verified it would run correctly, remove `@echo` to have it actually rename files.

Comment: Suppose a file is called `abc_def_2.txt`. Then your code would rename it to `abc.txt`, which is not the expected result.

Comment: @and31415 yes good catch - funny I just noticed this myself and was about to add a warning :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one-liner for doing it with [JP Software's Take Command](http://jpsoft.com/take-command-windows-scripting.html), a command interpreter whose `REN` command supports regular expressions:

```
ren ::(.*)_2\.(.*) ::\1.\2
```

### Further reading

- JP Software. [*REN*](http://jpsoft.com/help/ren.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know a really quick and dirty way of doing it.

But, how about piping a bare directory list to a TXT file. Load the file to a spreadsheet and create formula(s) to create the rename commands. Then you can copy the rename commands as values and paste it to a batch file that can be run to do the renames.