# Rename multiple files in folder

Tags: command-line, rename

I have some files in my folder like:

```
asd55.png
qwe55.png
zxc55.png
```

I want to remove the 55 and get the result:

```
asd.png
qwe.png
zxc.png
```

I tried with:

```
ren *55.png *.png
```

but doesnt work.

**NOTE:**

I have different name sizes like:

```
asd55.png
qwerty55.png
```

Comment: ren ???55.png ???

See http://superuser.com/q/475874/109090 for an explanation

Comment: @dbenham The command should be `ren ???55.png ???.png` The only caveat is that it only works if the file name length is always 5 (3+2). For a more generic solution, a batch script is the only way to go, I guess.

Comment: well I have some different file name sizes. like wioqetr55.png and jsad55.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch Renaming Automation \*\_2.\* TO \*.\*](http://superuser.com/questions/720502/batch-renaming-automation-2-to)

Comment: the soultion gived by @and31415 worked for me :)

Comment: @and31415 - Yes, that was my intent. Just a momentary brain fart when I originally typed.

Answer (score 1):

```
ren ???55.png ???.png
```

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for an explanation

If the number of characters before 55 varies, then you will probably want to use a batch script. (Could be done with a fairly complicated one liner on the command line, but not worth it)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /a-d ?*55.png') do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  ren "%%F" "!name:~0,-2!%%~xF"
)
```

If any file name might contain `!`, then delayed expansion must be toggled on and off within the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /a-d ?*55.png') do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  set "ext=%%~xF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!name!!ext!" "!name:~0,-2!!ext!"
  endlocal
)
```