# Bulk edit txt names

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I'm on windows 7 and have a folder of txt and all txt are 
named

> keyword_uniqueFileName.txt
>
> keyword_uniqueFileName2.txt
>
> keyword_uniqueFileName3.txt

and would like to bulk change them to

> MyNewKeyword_uniqueFileName.txt
>
> MyNewKeyword_uniqueFileName2.txt
>
> MyNewKeyword_uniqueFileName3.txt

Either using some program or the command line.

Worst case I'll have to go to my Kubuntu machine and use some command there.

Answer (score 1):

Within a command line window ("DOS box"), try

```
ren keyword_uniqueFilename*.txt MyNewKeyword_uniqueFilename*.txt
```

Comment: but then I will have to modify the command for each file?

Comment: @user1603548 No, if your file names are as listed in the question and should be modified as listed in the question, then this one line command will perform the renaming exactly as desired.

Comment: @user1603548 refer : [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](http://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards)

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell :

`powershell -C "gci | % {rni $_.Name ($_.Name -replace 'keyword', 'MyNewKeyword')}"`

## Explanation

`powershell -C "..."` launches a PowerShell session to run the quoted command. It returns to the outer shell when the command completes. `-C` is short for `-Command`.

`gci` returns all the files in the current directory. It is an alias for [`Get-ChildItem`][gci].

`| % {...}` makes a pipeline to process each file. `%` is an alias for [`Foreach-Object`][%].

`$_.Name` is the name of the current file in the pipeline.

`($_.Name -replace 'KW1', 'KW2')` uses the [`-replace`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) operator to create the new file name. Each occurrence of the first substring is replaced with the second substring.

`rni` changes the name of each file. The first parameter (called `-Path`) identifies the file. The second parameter (called `-NewName`) specifies the new name. `rni` is an alias for [Rename-Item][rni].

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746013/2142994)