# How to rename multiple files by adding or removing suffix or prefix in windows?

Tags: windows, rename

I have multiple files in a folder all the different name in windows with common suffix say `_(new)`. Example:

```
File Name_(new).mp4
```

How do I rename all the files by removing the suffix `_(new)` but not changing the name of the files?

Comment: Simple solution using [JREN.BAT renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) (pure script): `jren "_\(new\)\.mp4$" ".mp4" /i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the `REN` or `RENAME` command in Command Prompt should work for you:

<sub>Assuming the type is always `.mp4`:</sub>

```
RENAME *_(new).mp4 *.mp4
```

Otherwise, the following should work:

```
RENAME *_(new).* *.*
```

First, you want to `CD` into the folder it's in.

If you start your computer normally, CMD should put you in your user folder, e.g:

> ```
> C:\Users\Macraze
> ```
>
> or it might put you in the `system32` folder:
>
> ```
> C:\windows\system32
> ```

Either way, you can `CD` into the folder you want by typing something like:

> ```
> C:\Users\Macraze> CD Downloads
> //whoops, wrong folder, you can just 'CD ../' out
> C:\Users\Macraze\Downloads> CD ../
> C:\Users\Macraze> CD Desktop
> C:\Users\Macraze\Desktop> CD Misc
> C:\Users\Macraze\Desktop\Misc> RENAME *_(new).* *.*
> ```

---

When you run this command, the asterisk `*` is called a wildcard, meaning all content that matches the rule of having `_(new).` in between the filename / extension will get renamed.

Comment: how do I specify the folder? Would the prompt rename all files in my computer?

Comment: No, CMD will start in a specific folder and you can CD into a specific folder (and CD ../ out), or drag the folder icon into CMD after CD to specify the folder

Comment: Input example @MattFrear?

Comment: @MattFrear try my update

Comment: C:\Users\mattf\Desktop\Stored Procedures>dir /b
CollectionPointProviderDeliveryOptionTypeCountryExportSelect.sql
CollectionPointProviderExportSelect.sql
CountryDutyExportSelect.sql
CountryExportSelect.sql
CountrySubscriptionExportSelect.sql

C:\Users\mattf\Desktop\Stored Procedures>RENAME \*_(new).\* \*.\*
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\mattf\Desktop\Stored Procedures>

Comment: @MattFrear probably because the author of the question is talking about renaming files being suffixed with `_(new)`, your files aren't.

Comment: It makes no sense for this answer to be accepted. The proposed command has absolutely no effect, and it certainly does not answer the question.

Comment: @dbenham, then add an answer. Vandalising the post is immature and childish.

Comment: @Quill - I did not vandalize the answer - I added factual information without making any judgment. Had the question not been closed, then I would have provided my own answer, and included information as to why your answer is wrong. I chose to edit your answer and add a disclaimer at the top because I am afraid many readers will not read late arriving comments, and your answer can lead unsuspecting readers down the wrong path, as evidenced by 5th comment at http://superuser.com/q/1120265/109090. I suggest you test your code and prove to yourself it doesn't work, and then delete your answer.

Comment: For an explanation of why a simple REN command cannot solve this problem, see http://superuser.com/q/475874/109090

Comment: Here, this disgusting monstrosity will work: `cmd /V:ON /s /c "set "suffix=_(new)" && set "ext=mp4" && for /F "delims=" %F in ('dir /B "*!suffix!.!ext!"') do @(set "_tmp=%F" && cmd /s /c "rename "%_tmp%" "%_tmp:!suffix!=%"")"` Just change the "suffix=_(new)" and "ext=mp4" parts to whatever you need. 
If you want to see it without it actually doing it just add an `echo` statement before the `rename` It's all inclusive and turns on delayed expansion with the `/v:on` which contributes, a lot, to why it's so ugly. If put in a batch file make sure to use %%F instead of %F.

Comment: @Quill, what if it were a prefix: such as New_Filename.ext -> Filename.ext

Comment: **what if the filenames contain spaces?** For example, the following does not seem to be working: `ren "Part with spaces-"*.txt "Desired new part"*.txt`

Comment: Something seems to have changed. `RENAME *_(new).mp4 *.mp4` does nothing for me for the file `File Name_(new).mp4` on Windows 10 21H1

Comment: Does not work for me either.