# removal of suffixes from multiple files in windows - not duplicate

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

This may appear as a duplicate question but it is not.  My problem is a little different.  Actually, I had a folder with a lot of mp4 files and I wanted to suffix each of the file names with GOOD. Seeing answers to the previous question I did something and ended up actually suffixing with .mp4good.  Thus a file originally a.mp4 became a.mp4good.mp4 instead of aGOOD.mp4 (what I actually wanted).  Luckily, all these files are running but the names are not what I wanted.  I request help how to get what I want from this point.  I used rename command in DOS from the folder containing these files.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As I told before, I followed the answer in original question on the same topic.   so I did  execute at the command the following:                                    rename *.mp4 *GOOD.mp4

Comment: That doesn't help when you don't link to the original question ...

Comment: As I told before, I followed the answer in original question on the same topic.   so I did  execute at the command the following:                                    rename *.mp4 *GOOD.mp4      and I did not get what I wanted.  Instead of a.mp4 becoming aGOOD.mp4 it became amp4GOOD,mp4.  I want now that amp4GOOD,mp4 becomes aGOOD.mp4

Comment: The original question link is http://superuser.com/questions/961999/how-to-rename-multiple-files-by-adding-or-removing-suffix-or-prefix-in-windows

Comment: Sorry, a small error:  Instead of a.mp4 becoming aGOOD.mp4 it became a.mp4GOOD,mp4. I want now that a.mp4GOOD,mp4 becomes aGOOD.mp4

Comment: @SeethaRamaRajuSanapala - The accepted answer to that linked question is completely WRONG! You should disregard it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, the syntax you used to append a suffix to the base name was incorrect. An explanation as to why can be found at  [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards). That link also has the correct syntax to append to the base name:

```
ren *.mp4 ??????????????????GOOD.*
```

There must be enough `?` to match the length of the longest base name.

Note that if you have some starting names of the form `a.b.mp4`, then the above will yield `aGOOD.b.mp4`. If you want `a.bGOOD.mp4`, then you need more than a simple REN command. You could use

```
for %F in (*.mp4) do @ren "%F" "%~nFGOOD.mp4"
```

If you put the command in a batch script then you must double the percents

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.mp4) do ren "%%F" "%%~nFGOOD.mp4"
```

Currently you have names of the form `a.mp4GOOD.mp4`, and you want `aGOOD.mp4`.

The solution is:

```
ren *.mp4GOOD.mp4 ??????????????????GOOD.mp4
```

If some names have more than two dots, then again you will need more than a simple REN command.

```
for %A in (*.mp4GOOD.mp4) do @for %B in ("%~nA") do @ren "%B" "%~nBGOOD.mp4
```

Remember to double the percents if you put the command in a batch script.

Comment: @dbenham : Thank you so much!  You have given more than what I asked for.  Pointers and references.