# How to batch remove a duplicate file extension in OS

Tags: command-line, batch

I have multiple files named "*.txt.jpg" (don't ask...) in a single directory. I would like to remove the ".txt" portion so the result becomes "*.jpg" only so I can then import them into Photos.

Any suggestions? I looked at previous Q/A involving the mv command but couldn't quite figure out how to write the correct command. I don't want to mess further. Thanks

Comment: What is your Operating System? Scripting language? As it stand your question is impossible to answer. Also, please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill At first look, I thought he meant batch as in "batch programming in Windows" as the tags of the question were *command-line* and *batch*, but on further reading, he has mentioned the mv command, which means he is talking about Unix/Linux.

Comment: Have you tried just using the files as-is.  Some software doesn't care about multiple extensions and uses the last one.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows, and if there are no additional dots in any of the file names, then you can use the following:

```
ren *.txt.jpg ???????????????????????????????????????????????????.jpg
```

There must be enough `?` to match the length of the longest file name. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for more info.

If some files have more than two dots, then you will need more than a simple REN command. The following should remove the unwanted `.txt` regardless how many dots are in the original name.

```
for %A in (*.txt.jpg) do @for %B in ("%~nA") do @ren "%A" "%~nB.jpg"
```

If you put the command within a batch script then you must double the percents:

```
@echo off
for %%A in (*.txt.jpg) do for %%B in ("%%~nA") do ren "%%A" "%%~nB.jpg"
```

Comment: Could you show how to remove __repeated__ (arbitrary) extensions? That is, `aaa.txt.txt` and `bbb.txt.txt.txt` should become `aaa.txt` and `bbb.txt`, but `ccc.jpg.png` should not be changed. I would be happy to create a separate question if you think it would be better.

Comment: @johnc.j. - That is not easy to do with pure batch. But I have written a [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) (hybrid JScript/batch) that simplifies the task: `jren "(\.[^.]+)\1+$" "$1"`

Comment: Very interesting, I will take a look today :)