# Why does ren leave "e" on simple rename task

Tags: command-line, batch, rename

I have lists of files I would like to batch rename.

Source files names are "SlideXX.BMP" (XX being number from 1 to whatever).

I would like to rename them all to "bbrdXX.BMP"

When I perform `ren Slide* bbrd*` the ren performs but unlike expected everything becomes "bbrd**e**XX.BMP".

Why does this occur?

Comment: Your rename command if replacing the first four characters of the file names, so the fifth character `e` is retained from the original file name. To do what you want will require quite complex scripting, unless you use a third-party renamer.

Comment: this would do what you want, in PowerShell: `$x = gci C:\yourpath | % { gi $_.FullName  | rni -newname ($_ -replace "Slide","bbrd") }`. if you have the files in folders and subfolders, search for files recursively and add `-r` to the `gci` call

Comment: This certainly did it! Thank you very much! If you do not mind would you mind explaining meaning of  `| %`?

Comment: [This thread](https://superuser.com/q/475874) perfectly explains the behaviour…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with PowerShell on this, in cmd it could be a little more complicated to achieve what you want.

```
$x = gci C:\yourpath | % { gi $_.FullName | rni -newname ($_ -replace "Slide","bbrd") }
```

In Detail:

- First it searches for all files inside the directory with `Get-ChildItem` alias `gci`
- Then it will loop over each file with `foreach-object` alias `%`
- Then it calls the Item by it's `fullname` property with `get-item` alias `gi`
- The Item then gets passed into the pipeline and renamed by `rename-item` alias `rni`
- Inside the `rni` part, it replaces `Slide` with `bbrd` for the current object and will be saved with the new name.

to run this recursively if you have subfolders which also have files inside which need to be renamed, just add `-r` to your `gci` call and also add a `filter` to only target the files you want:

`$x = gci C:\yourpath -r -filter *.bmp | % { [...] }`

Answer (score 0):

Slide is 5 letters long. BBRD is 4 letters long. If you can use bbrd_ then the e will get replaced also. If you are willing to do two steps :

- ren "Slide*" "/*.*"
- ren lide* bbcd*

The first ren strips the S or reduces the length by one.  The second ren then does the conversion to bbrd without error since lide has 4 letters also

Comment: Does the first `ren` work? It tells me that "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: oops a period crept in, I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in batch there is `complex` scripting required. It is as simple as

```bat
@echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (Slide*.bmp) do Set A=%%~nxA&Ren "%%A" "!A:Slide=bbrd!"
```

If DelayedExpansion is Enabled by default it is also a console one liner:

```
for %A in (Slide*.bmp) do Set A=%~nxA&Ren "%A" "!A:Slide=bbrd!"
```