# Windows CMD: Add Suffix to all files in folder

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, batch-rename

I have a folder with 120 `.cs` files.

What I need to do is add "DO" to every files name, before the extension.

Heres what i came up with:

```
ren *.cs *. //this removes all file extensions
ren *.* *DO.cs // this should rename all the files and add the suffixes
```

Now, this works mostly. But not for some Files.

Initially, I thought that it was just the files starting with `Do`

But... well, here is how it turned out:

[image: folder-view]

(The rest thats not on the printscreen is fine)

Now this aint a serious problem; id just like to understand why it did this...

There is my cmd output:
[image: cmd output]

From looking at this output i thought maybe it cant find the files because the second command consists of *.* for the renaming; but since none of the files in the folder has a file extension at the moment of renaming; this cant be it..

Thanks

Comment: just a guess, but short names may be interfering here (see http://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards).

Comment: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](http://superuser.com/q/475874/241386)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc this is the exact same answer that is already posted a centimeter above your comment.. not that helpful.

Comment: @MasterAzazel this is **not** an answer and so is the comment above me. That wasn't clear so I didn't look at his link and don't know that it was posted before. It's not helpful because you didn't read it

Comment: answer/question call it whatever you want; still the same link.
and indeed i have read it. that is why the first to post it got an upvote from me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others told, it lies in the way `ren` interprets wildcards, that's why it can't find files that contains dots `*.*` in second command, because:

- You not only removed file extension using first command, but also dots before the extensions:

`Artikelnummer.cs > Artikelnummer`

- And your second command is looking for filenames containing `.` (which there's none!):

`ren *.*`

- Also consider `ren` uses `*` to refer to file name, so when you look for `*.*` (any name, any extension) you're using `*` to refer to filename and extension at the same time, which is confusing to `ren` command!

So, the conclusion is, the only problem was `*.*`, replace it with `*`:

```
ren *.cs *.DO.cs
ren * *DO.cs
```

However, if you want to rename by running a single line of code:

From a command prompt run:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('dir /b "%FilesLocation%"') do if %~xa EQU .cs ren "%a" "%~naDO.cs"
```

Or save and run this script:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%FilesLocation%"') do if %%~xa EQU .cs ren "%%a" "%%~naDO.cs"
```

And don't forget to change `%FilesLocation%` with it's real value.

Comment: thanks for clarifying.
wont that rename everything to `.DO.cs?`

what I need is `xyDO.cs`

Comment: Updated my answer, see if it works.

Comment: isnt there a way to do this using the ren command?

Comment: It's a `ren` command inside a `for` loop. But if you mean JUST `ren` command, I updated my entire answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a way to add **suffix "_t"** to my images.

Just one simple **PowerShell command** did it !

```
CD "target folder path here"
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.basename + "_Suffix” + $_.extension}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked very well for me and is very intuitive, however  as someone who normally doesn't mess with CMD or PowerShell I would be a lot more comfortable implementing it in a business process if this was the accepted answer and had hundreds of upvotes :).  Can any super guru confirm this is a safe method and there aren't any `gotchas`?  (eg what happens if there are duplicate file names, filenames with weird characters or extensions, if there are subfolders etc).  This is what I used when I was in a folder:  `Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { "my_lovely_prefix_” + $_.basename + $_.extension}`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the for command. Off the top of my head, it goes something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=." %a in ('dir *.cs /b') do (ren %a.%b %aDO.%b)
```

This does not work for filenames that contain more than one point though.

Comment: i know theres other ways to do it; but im wondering why it acted like it did the way i tried to do it

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Maybe ren *.* acts on the files in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

`FOR` has a mode to loop through files (also recursively), no `dir /b` is required (https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html). You need to pass a file glob or a list `(*.cs, \path\*.txt,...)`

**Command line**

```
FOR %_ IN (*.cs) DO @REN "%_" "%~n_DO.*"
```

**In a batch file *(use `%%`*)**

```
FOR %%_ IN (*.cs) DO @REN "%%_" "%%~n_DO.*"
```

*Notes:*

- *`%_` is a valid variable*
- *`@` is to not dump rename commands for each filename*
- *`%~n_` returns only the name portion from `%_` (removes the last extension)*
- *Add `/R "c:\directory"` to recursively parse a directory (https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html). Use with caution - there is no undo*
- *Double quotes `"` are important because paths and filenames may include spaces*
- *Won't work as expected with multiple extensions because in Windows only the last token is considered an extension. I.e. **test.tar.gz** will become **test.tarDO.gz***

I suggest you first try with `FOR %_ IN (*.cs) DO echo REN "%_" "%~n_DO.*"` for dry-run