# Renaming multiple folders. Trimming down to first x characters

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, rename, bulk

Simple example: (my problem is involving thousands of folders)

I have two folders with the names:

"A0000001_words_letters"

"A0000002_lots_of_numbers"

How would I automatically trim all folder names to just contain the AXXXXXXX start. This start will always be the same number of characters so effectively just keeping the first x characters of the name.

Thanks

Comment: You getting any of my messages? Have you see [Accepting an Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so you understand how that works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop to set delimiters and tokens parsing folder name parts and use those to set variables for later use with the [REN](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) command.

You also want to utilize the [Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to handle the expanding of the variables set in the loop accordingly to be properly used (not parsed at runtime) with the rename command per iteration within the loop.

```
@ECHO

SET srcdir=C:\folder\path
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B /AD "%srcdir%\*"') DO (
    SET fname=%%~F
    SET fname=!fname:~0,8!
    SET fname=!fname!
    REN "%srcdir%\%%~XNF" "!fname!"
)
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [**Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion**](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [**REN**](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)

Answer (score 1):

If there is always an `_` after the first x characters, then the following will work from the command line (no batch needed)

```
for /d %A in (*) do @for /f "delims=_ eol=_" %B in ("%A") do ren "%A" "%B"
```

Double the percents if you put the above command within a batch script.

If you cannot rely on `_` after the first x characters, then this command should work from the command line, preserving the fist 8 characters:

```
for /d %A in (*) do @set "folder=%A"&call ren "%^folder%" "%^folder:~0,8%"
```

Or you could use this batch scrip to preserve the first 8 characters:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%A in (*) do (
  set "folder=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!folder!" "!folder:~0,8!"
  endlocal
)
```

Or you could use my [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). It is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required.

Remove everything from the first `_` onward

```
jren "_.*" "" /d
```

Preserve the first 8 characters

```
jren "^(.{8}).*" "$1" /d
```

***Note:*** 
If you were trying to rename files instead of folders, then you could do something like

```
ren *.txt ????????.txt
```

But unfortunately, you cannot use wildcards when renaming folders. So this technique is useless for folders. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for more info.