# Rename Files in Folders

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2016, batch-rename

My goal is to create something in my Windows Server 2016 that renames all files in a folder continuously. But, I do not know a way of doing so. I have done some research about this but I only have found tools that rename files when you click it. What I want to do is create a continuous schedule that everytime that it's created a file in an folder it renames it with a prefix, with the date and hour etc.

Does any of you know any way of doing so ?

Thank you.

Edit:
What I want to do specifically is to create a continuous loop that renames All files in a folder, with any name, where it adds an prefix with date and hour

Comment: Where will create the file?

Comment: @itwasnotme in a specific folder of my server.

Comment: In one folder and/or too in sub folder?

Comment: Create a script (VBS or PS) which performs scanning of folder(s) content (maybe including subfolders) and renaming files (with checking that the file have not a prefix yet and is not opened by any process), and shedule it with some reasonable period.

Comment: @itwasnotme in a folder !

Comment: @Akina I am not good in VBS could you give me some basic codes to use in that script? I know its asking too much but I would appreciate it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple `.bat` file can do the job:

```
@ECHO OFF
:loop
  ren old*.oldname new*.newname
  timeout /t 5 > NUL
goto loop
```

For more complicated renames see the article
[How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards)

Comment: This is a good start, thank you for that, but how do I make it rename all the files in a folder? That script only renames files with a certain name right?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do. You will need a more complicated batch file for more complicated rules. You could add some examples in the post.

Comment: What I want to do specifically is to create a continuous loop that renames All files in a folder, with any name, where it adds an prefix with date and hour

Comment: Meaning that it will rename again files that were previously renamed? Why?

Comment: That'ts true, I'm stupid, I dont want it to rename files that were before renamed with date and hour

Comment: You need to have some identifying string for files that were already renamed. If you can come up with a simple rule, the `.bat` file can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

My suggest for do this job, add some character in name, like code (for sample) using "#", filter files by list and if not match, rename it...

Sorry my *limited English*...

```cmd
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

mode 50,4 & color 9F & title <nul & cls

rem :: go to the target folder, by edit 'set command in [set "_path_to_ren=."]' and repace to:
rem :: 'set "_path_to_ren=."' by set/add your full target path: "d:\folder\where\are\this\files"

set "_path_to_ren=." & cd /d "!_path_to_ren!"

:^| 
title <nul & echo/ & echo/ Working in looping... & echo ========================== 
    
for /f %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe OS Get localdatetime^|find "."')do set "_dt=%%~i"
title Renaming in Looping: !_dt:~0,4!/!_dt:~4,2!/!_dt:~6,2! !_dt:~8,2!:!_dt:~10,2!:!_dt:~15,2! 

for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe .:"*"^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /v \\#[0-9]^|find/v "%~0"
')do 2>nul ren "%%~i" "#!_dt:~0,4!-!_dt:~4,2!-!_dt:~6,2!-!_dt:~8,2!-!_dt:~10,2!-!_dt:~12,2!_%%~nxi" >nul

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe /t 1 >nul & goto :^|
```

**`| LoopRen.cmd |`** :  **<kbd>`FileName.Ext`</kbd>**

**`| Get Results |`** :  **<kbd>`#2020-06-28-13-00-57_FileName.Ext`</kbd>**

---

[image]

---

**Obs.:** Get date by **`wmic`** following this:

---

> [Safe way to get current day month and year in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635541/safe-way-to-get-current-day-month-and-year-in-batch)
>
> [Parsing Dates in Batch Files & Regional Settings / Locale](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/02/parsing-dates-in-batch-files-regional-settings-locale/)