# Windows rename multiple files

Tags: cmd.exe, rename, batch-rename

I have a folder with images :

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
...
11000.png.
```

And I want to rename this files adding a p- as follows:

```
p-1.png
p-2.png
...
p-11000.png
```

How can I achieve this? I tried

```
ren *.png ???-p.*
```

but this is giving the opposite results.

Comment: You can use either a batch script or a tool like https://www.den4b.com/products/renamer . Look also at the **Related** links on the right of this page.

Comment: some more info on ren can be found here : https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards

Comment: @NexussimLements .... Did you look over the cmd batch file rename method as described and such below which I wrote up for you a while back?

Comment: @Pimp Juice IT Yes , it worked like a charm. Thanks (I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use some more direct and simple `for` loop command?

- You don't need for any `if` in your loop:

```bat
❌ ren *.png ???-p.*  
✅ ren *.png p-*.png  
for %i in ("c:\your\folder\*.png")do ren "%~i" "p-%~nxi"
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[ren /? | rename /?](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)**

Answer (score 2):

### Append a string (or characters) to the beginning of file names

You can use a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop to iterate each file in a directory and use [variable substitutions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to get the specific name portion of each file. You can use those and add in the "`p-`" string and append it as a prefix with the `ren` command for each file getting the expected output result you desire.

> **Essentially this. . .**
>
> - Iterates all `*.*` files in a specific directory (not recursively)
> - Uses [variable substitutions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) for getting the file name portions from each file
> - Appends the `p-` string to the beginning of each files and passes that per file as the second argument to the [ren](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) command for the new name

---

**Command Line**

```
for %a in ("C:\path\*.*") do if [%~xa]==[.png] ren "%~a" "p-%~Na%~Xa"
```

**Batch Script**

```
SET "Src=C:\path"
SET "Str=p-"
for %%a in ("%Src%\*.*") do if [%%~xa]==[.png] ren "%%~a" "%Str%%%~Na%%~Xa"
```

---

### Further Resources

[FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

- **Variable Substitutions (FOR /?)**

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > ```
- [Ren](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)
- [Variable Substitutions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- [If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Answer (score 0):

Total Commander has a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> nice filename changing tool.

It can replace strings, use RegEx, counter, range of characters, upper/lower-case and few other.