# Windows rename multiple images

Tags: cmd.exe, rename, batch-rename

I have a folder containing only images:

```
1.png
2.png
...
11000.png
```

I want to rename these files, adding a `p` as follows:

```
p1.png
p2.png
...
p11000.png
```

How can I achieve this, as I've tried the following, but it's not working:

```powershell
Ren *.png ???p.*
```

Comment: You asked for a command to do it, but you might like to know about [PowerRename](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/wiki/PowerRename-Overview) as an option in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows rename multiple files](https://superuser.com/questions/1459634/windows-rename-multiple-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`ren`](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html):

```powershell
Ren "*.png" "p*.png"
for %i in ("c:\your\folder\*.png")do ren "%~i" "p%~nxi"

rem :: in bat file: 
for %%i in ("c:\your\folder\*.png")do ren "%%~i" "p%%~nxi"
```

- In PowerShell:

```powershell
get-item c:\your\folder\*.png | ren -newname {"p"+$_.name}
```

- Or PowerShell in cmd:

```powershell
powershell -nop -c "Get-Item 'c:\your\folder\*.png' | ren -newname {'p'+$_.name}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this using Powershell:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem "Filepath" -Filter *.png | Rename-Item -Newname {"p" + $_.name}
```

Short style:

```powershell
Ls "Filepath" -filter *.png | Ren -newname {"p"+$_.name}
```

A bit longer batch style:

```powershell
@cd "Filepath" & @for %%a in (*.png) do Ren "%%~nxa" "p%%~nxa"
```