# Using Windows rename to replace a single underscore with a double?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, rename, batch-rename

Can anyone advise me where I am going wrong with this? I have some file names that contain `XXX XXX_Layer_XXX` and I'm trying to replace to `XXX XXX_Layer__XXX`

My attempt so far was:

```
ren  "*Layer_*.*"  "*Layer__*.*"
```

But that does not seem to be working as expected!

Comment: `rename` is an internal command of cmd and has nothing to do with Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer tried to use the `ren` command and failed, because this
command only does a very primitive string matching.
Most importantly, it cannot replace a string with a longer one.

To prevent others from making the same mistake, here is an explanation
(not an answer).

If the command is written as:

```
ren SourceMask TargetMask
```

then any character in `TargetMask` causes the pointer into
`SourceMask` to advance by one position.

So, if we are renaming the file `1234.567` by the following command:

```
ren *2*.* *2X*.*
```

the result will be `12X4.567`. It will **not** be the naively expected
`12X34.567`.

The reason is that `TargetMask` is handled here like this:

```
*2 - matches up to and including 2, adding to target : 12
X - matches itself AND advances one position so skipping 3, adding to target : X
*. - matches up to and including the point, adding to target : 4.
* - matches the extension part, adding to target : 567
```

Conclusion: The `ren` command should be avoided when replacing strings
of unequal lengths.

The way `ren` works is described in a very complete manner in the post
[How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards).

Answer (score 1):

It should be much easier in PowerShell

```powershell
Get-ChildItem *Layer_* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -creplace '_Layer_', '_Layer__' } -WhatIf
```

Aliased version:

```powershell
ls *Layer_* | ren -Ne { $_.Name -creplace '_Layer_', '_Layer__' } -wi
```

After confirming the new names are correct just remove `-WhatIf` / `-wi` to do a real rename

In cmd the `rename` command does a greedy replacement in the target if it sees a `*` so your solution won't work. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/241386). You'll need to replace the string yourself. Something like this

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%d in (*_Layer_*) do (
    set "name=%%d"
    echo ren "!name!" "!name:_Layer_=_Layer__!"
)
```

The replacement is this part `!name:_Layer_=_Layer__!`. The syntax is `%variablename:text_to_find=text_to_replace%`