# Rename File with dashes Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line

So this works:

1. `File1-suffix.txt`
2. `ren "*-suffix.txt" "*-newsuffix.txt"`
3. `File1-newsuffix.txt`

But this fails:

1. `File1-suffixA-suffixB.txt`
2. `ren "*-suffixA-suffixB.txt" "*-newsuffixA-suffixB.txt"`
3. `File1-suffixA-newsuffixA-suffixB.txt`

Why is the original suffixA retained?

I have studied the documenation [here](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) & [here](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards#475875)

However I see nothing regarding dashes causing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ren` pattern substitution code does its job without any knowledge about what was originally matched by `*` in the "input" pattern – it only receives the replacement pattern and has to apply the wildcard rules anew. According to those rules, the function lets each `*` match as much as possible up to (not including) the *last* instance of the `-` character that follows; in your case, this means that the `*` in replacement pattern will match the entire `File1-suffixA`.

The source code indeed notes that it won't do the right thing in many cases. (See wildcard_rename() and WinEditName() in XPSP1/NT/base/cmd/cpwork.c on GitHub.)

Comment: Thank you, is there an alternative way of acheiving this rename on the Windows Command Line

Comment: PowerShell and its built-in regex substitution features.

Comment: sadly i cannot use powershell in this application

Comment: Possibly a `for` loop with Cmd's built-in string substitution, then? `%var:old=new%` seems like it should be enough for your specific example.